# Delete part between brackets in a string when it occurs at the end of the string in R using gsub

Tags: regex, r, replace, gsub

I am on the lookout for a gsub expression that would delete any part of a string between brackets, but only when it occurs at the end of that string. E.g. for

```
string="n-Pentacosane (C-25)"
```

I would like it to return just `"n-Pentacosane"`.
Important though is that it wouldn't delete anyting written between brackets earlier on in the string. Anybody any thoughts perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sub(' *\\([^)]*)$', '', "n-Pentacosane (C-25)")
```

That is:

- `sub` is enough, because we will do a single replacement
- To match the starting bracket we need to write: `\\(`. No need to escape the second.
- To match at the end, we need two things:

  1. match at the end using `$`
  2. make the matching *non-greedy*: by using `[^)]*` we avoid replacing too much in input like `penta (something) cosane (C-25)`, to get `penta (something) cosane` as result instead of `penta`

Comment: Thanks millions! I always keep on learning about the million possible uses of (g)sub! :-)